# Read .xls file with Missing Values using XLConnect

Tags: r, excel

When using `XLConnect` to read in a .xls file how do you set missing values. Similar to the `na.string==c()` argument in `read.csv`.

My current R code looks like this:

```
install.packages("XLConnect")
library(XLConnect)

excel.file <- file.path(".../FakeData.xls")
fake2 <- readWorksheetFromFile(excel.file, sheet="Sheet1", header=TRUE)
```

My fake data look like this:

```
ID  Age Weight      Gender
1   30  55          M
2   22  NA          F
3   33  80          NA
```

I want my NA values to be interpreted as missing, so that Weight and Gender are read into R as numeric/factor variables, respectively. Currently, they are being converted into character variables because of the NA values.

When I try:

```
setMissingValue(fake2, value = c("NA"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘setMissingValue’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call     `setMissingValue` on a workbook *object* not on the filename.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(excel.file)
setMissingValue(wb, value = c(""))

fake2 <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Sheet1", header=TRUE)
```